# Can Swagger in Asp.Net Core be made to produce documentation for classes that are not MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I have been looking for some clues about this without much luck. 
It looks like mvc core 2 stopped using IApiExplorer that I could find some examples of, so I am not really sure where to start.

In my core asp.net api app I have generic handlers that deal with many api calls. So rather than reading properties of MVC controller I need to generate swagger documentation from classes that represent api queries and commands.

I have classes that are decorated by custom attributes like these (simplified):

```
[ApiDriver("GetSomeResult",ApiType.Query, ApiHttpMethod.Get)]
public class MyQueryClass
{
    public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

where attribute is defined as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ApiDriverAttribute: Attribute
{
    public ApiDriverAttribute(string apiName, ApiType apiType, ApiHttpMethod httpMethod)
    {
        ApiName = apiName;
        ApiType = apiType;
        ApiHttpMethod = httpMethod;
    }

    public string ApiName { get; set; }
    public ApiType ApiType { get; set; }
    public ApiHttpMethod ApiHttpMethod { get; set; }
}


public enum ApiType { Command, Query}
public enum ApiHttpMethod { Post, Get }
```

So I need swagger to target (or I somehow need to provide data about) classes attributed in this way rather than going to MVC controllers.

Many thanks

Comment: That class (`MyQueryClass`) looks like a model, you can add models to the swagger doc, take a look here: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Blob _ Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, maybe. MyQueryClass is a bit more than just a model.It also defines route i.e. in the above case it would be api/query/GetSomeResult?myProperty=SomeStringValue. It also defines what HTTP method it supports. How is your model injected into documentation? That might give me a clue. Thank you.

Comment: Swagger is designed to documented API endpoints, which necessitates a controller action. Random classes would not be included because random classes aren't capable of being routed to, and thus don't provide any actual endpoint.

Comment: I beg to differ Chris. My query classes are perfectly routable. I have that bit working fine.  What I need is some way of explaining that to swagger. How does swagger know about controllers? Where does that information come from, what provides it and can I substitute that logic for something else? As I said, it used to be possible in previous versions using custom implementation of IApiExplorer.

Comment: @Zvirk did you have time to test my answer using the `IDocumentFilter` ? that is how I inject models into the documentation.

Comment: Thanks heldersepu but it doesn't help me. I downloaded  mvc core code to see how these things hang together. It looks like to much work to re-implement many of the registered providers. It looks like model and action descriptors are used by other mvc parts so not sure if they are possible to replace without breaking something fundamental.

Comment: My plan B is to create my own Swagger controller and produce swagger.json that can be used for UI generation. As I have all of my data available and in one place I am hoping this will not be too hard.  I am just exploring swagger json structure and will update this question when I get somewhere.

Comment: I have not managed to plug Swagger in just yet, but have just published a routable dto framework to: https://github.com/zakkra/RoutableDto. This is where I need Swagger plugged in so I guess I will be looking into it again soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now integrated answer to this question in [Routable Dto solution](https://github.com/riskfirst/RoutableDto), see RoutableDtoSwaggerGenerator class.

The answer was relatively simple. I had to create an implementation of IDocumentFilter and populate swagger document paths, operations, parameters and responses from my own routing repository.

All I had to do then is register my filter within overall SwaggerGen registration in StartUp.

Hope this helps someone and saves some time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I inject models into the documentation:

```
private class ApplyDocumentVendorExtensions : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument sd, SchemaRegistry sr, IApiExplorer ae)
    {
        sr.GetOrRegister(typeof(ExtraType));
        //sr.GetOrRegister(typeof(BigClass));        
    }
}
```

Here is the full code on GitHub [SwaggerConfig.cs](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs)

It might be slightly different for you because I'm not net-core

Comment: This actually ended up being a part of solution, thank you.